# extern "C" char** environ - Windows - C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, porting

I have some old linux code I'm trying to port to Windows.
When I first built it as a straight native DLL, I go no issues with this piece of code, but when I tried making it a mixed-mode C++/CLI DLL, I got an unresolved external object error on this:

```
extern "C" char** environ;
```

Why would this work for native and not CLI? 
Any idea how to work around this, or what it even does?

Comment: which `/clr` option are you using: `/clr`, `/clr:pure`, or `/clr:safe`

Answer (score 2):

That holds the environment variables (PATH, etc, etc). The C standard (if i recall correctly) requires `environ` to point to an array of these variables. They're also passed as the 3rd argument to the `main` entry point function.

Apparently, for some reason, the C++/CLI doesn't initialize that.

To fix that, you can allocate it yourself and fill with either either [getenv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/) (C) or [Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h5xxewc.aspx) (Managed C++). I don't know of any in-place fix, but it shouldn't be too hard.