# Get all env variables in C\C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, c, environment-variables

The signature for the main function in C\C++ can include 3 arguments:

```
main( int argc, char *argv[ ], char *envp[ ] )
```

The third is the environment variables.

I'm compiling a library under VS10 and therefor I have no `main()`. How can I get the environment variables in exactly the same type as is in `char *envp[]`? I rather not use .NET as to decrease dependencies and perhaps one day be open to portability.

Comment: getenv() and setenv() cannot be used because you want to know the whole list... but if you're using Visual Studio then you develop application for Windows, so what about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692855/extern-c-char-environ-windows-c-cli (possibly even a dupe)

Comment: I suggest you do not try to write multi-language source files.

Comment: maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631664/accessing-environment-variables-in-c

Answer (score 8):

[`GetEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a (read-only!) pointer to the start of the environment block for a process.

The block is a contiguous C-style string that contains null-terminated `key=value` pairs. The block is ended by an additional null termination.

To make access more convenient, use something like the following function:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring; // Generally convenient
typedef std::map<tstring, tstring> environment_t;

environment_t get_env() {
    environment_t env;

    auto free = [](LPTCH p) { FreeEnvironmentStrings(p); };
    auto env_block = std::unique_ptr<TCHAR, decltype(free)>{
            GetEnvironmentStrings(), free};

    for (LPTCH i = env_block.get(); *i != T('\0'); ++i) {
        tstring key;
        tstring value;

        for (; *i != T('='); ++i)
            key += *i;
        ++i;
        for (; *i != T('\0'); ++i)
            value += *i;

        env[key] = value;
    }

    return env;
}
```

Of course, a proper implementation would encapsulate this in a class, and probably use `std::stringstream` rather than manually iterating over the characters, concatenating the strings on `char` at a time. But I’m lazy.

Usage is like this:

```
environment_t env = get_env();

// Now you can write env[T("Var1")] to access a variable.
```

Comment: Can I then cast `char*[]` on the return value? Could you add this syntax if possible to your answer?

Comment: @Jonathan No you cannot, `LPTCH` is a typedef for `TCHAR*`. It’s a *single* contiguous string, not an array of strings. Since your question is tagged, the easiest way to work with this mess is to parse it and put it in a vector. Wait …

Comment: I think that should be singular "GetEnvironmentVariable": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

However this requires knowing the name of the variable in advance.

Comment: Please note that according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683187(v=vs.85).aspx one should release the env block via calling to FreeEnvironmentStrings()

Comment: Should add e.g. `i != nullptr` in the for loop condition so that the unlikely case where `GetEnvironmentStrings` returns NULL is also covered.

Comment: Also: some 'hidden' vars can actually start with '=' so you might want to exclude those instead of adding empty keys. See source of `GetEnvironmentVariables` in https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs for a rather complete implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about windows, but on Linux this variable:

```
extern char **environ;
```

is exactly what you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

extern char **environ;

int main (int ac, char **av, char **envp) {

  assert(envp == environ);

}
```

Comment: `#include <unistd.h>` should declare `environ` these days.  There was a time when `environ` was the only variable without a header declaring it, but they finally fixed that.

Comment: Given the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370399/c-function-arg-char-is-not-the-same-as-char), I guess that `char **environ` and `char *envp[]` are of the same type

Answer (score 2):

The following is based of [@Konrad's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535168/552510), with 2 main differences:

- Using `wchar_t` rather than `TCHAR`. No one should be using non-wide chars in Windows.
- Constructing `key` and `value` using `std::wstring str(buffer, buflen)`, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/896148/552510). I believe performance should be better than concating char-by-char, though I haven't measured it.

code:

```
typedef std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> environment_t;
environment_t get_env() {
    environment_t env;

    auto free = [](wchar_t* p) { FreeEnvironmentStrings(p); };
    auto env_block = std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(free)>{
        GetEnvironmentStringsW(), free};

    for (const wchar_t* name = env_block.get(); *name != L'\0'; )
    {
        const wchar_t* equal = wcschr(name, L'=');
        std::wstring key(name, equal - name);

        const wchar_t* pValue = equal + 1;
        std::wstring value(pValue);

        env[key] = value;

        name = pValue + value.length() + 1;
    }

    return env;
}
```

Comment: "No one should be using non-wide chars in Windows." - not anymore, true. On the other hand when `_UNICODE` macro is defined `TCHAR` expands to `WCHAR` which expands to `wchar_t` if the compiler supports it.

Comment: @orhtej2: You're right. However, I don't think code should depends on *whether* a macro is defined and *whether* compiler supports `wchar_t`, which can be disabled in an [MSVC compiler settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type)

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of the existing answers in this question from Konrad and Jonathan that might help anyone wanting to create a single widechar string for logging to file or (in my case) for remote diagnostics.  Feel free to upvote them instead.

```
LPWCH we = GetEnvironmentStrings();
const wchar_t* w = we;
do {
    eline = w;
    w += eline.length() + 1;
    env += eline;
    env += L"\r\n";
} while ((eline.length() > 0) && (*w != L'\0'));
FreeEnvironmentStrings(we);
```